# How to customize the table header and table row with a background color in LWUIT

Tags: themes, lwuit, tabular

I have created a table with the default table model that contains three columns and some rows, what I want to do is to customize the style of the header with a background color and also customize the background color of each rows with a different color than header colors.

Also I want to be able to set the size of each column to be different I want one columns to be larger than other two columns.

Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Set the styles for TableHeader and TableCell respectively.

If you want more control than that derive table and override:

```
protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable)
```